# How to avoid calling same function for a prop for a component : ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

Basically i am calling same function multiple times inside the component for a prop which is inside the render function.

How do i avoid calling the same function multiple times for a component required for that specific prop

Below is my code

```
getProperties = (name, param) => {
    switch(name){
        case 'duration':
            return param.obj1;
        case 'time':
            return param.obj2;
        case 'date':
            return param.obj3;
        case 'place':
            return param.obj4;
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <SampleComponent
            duration={this.getProperties('duration', param1)}
            time={this.getProperties('time', param2)}
            date={this.getProperties('date', param3)}
            place={this.getProperties('place', param4)}
    )
}
```

So instead of having multiple methods to get the required details. How to use single method which does manipulation and return object with transformed data?

Comment: Convert it into an arrow function where you're calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to clean up the code:

1. List down the parameters and have them in an array:

```js
const DURATION = "duration";
const TIME = "time";
const DATE = "date";
const PLACE = "place";


const allParamters = [DURATION, TIME, DATE, PLACE]
```

2. Prepare two objects, `paramMap` and `keyMap`

   - `paramMap` is the object to use to for given param.
   - `keyMap` is the map that would say which `key` to use for given param.

```js
const paramMap = {
  [DURATION]: param1,
  [TIME]: param2,
  [DATE]: param3,
  [PLACE]: param4
};

const keyMap = {
  [DURATION]: "obj1",
  [TIME]: "obj2",
  [DATE]: "obj3",
  [PLACE]: "obj4"
}
```

3. Update the getProperties function and prepare all the props in one place as:

```js
// for getProperties(DURATION), it will resolve to `param1.obj1!`
const getProperties = (key) => paramMap[key][keyMap[key]];


// this will prepare the `props` map as:
// { "duration": param1.obj1, ... }
const propsToPass = allParamters.reduce((props, aParam) => {
  props[aParam] = this.getProperties(aParam)
  return props;
}, {});
```

4. Finally, update the JSX:

```js
<SampleComponent {...propsToPass} />
```

All you need to do is define `paramMap` correctly where `param1`, `param2`, and others are in scope.

Here is the complete snippet:

```js
const DURATION = "duration";
const TIME = "time";
const DATE = "date";
const PLACE = "place";


const allParamters = [DURATION, TIME, DATE, PLACE]

const paramMap = {
  [DURATION]: param1,
  [TIME]: param2,
  [DATE]: param3,
  [PLACE]: param4
};

const keyMap = {
  [DURATION]: "obj1",
  [TIME]: "obj2",
  [DATE]: "obj3",
  [PLACE]: "obj4"
}

const getProperties = (key) => paramMap[key][keyMap[key]];

const propsToPass = allParamters.reduce((props, aParam) => {
  props[aParam] = this.getProperties(aParam)
  return props;
}, {});

<SampleComponent {...propsToPass} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. How is `keyMap` will be picked from `getProperties`

Comment: Ah wait, I will update my answer. It should be `const getProperties = (key) => paramMap[key][keyMap[key]];`

Comment: There are other changes as well.

Answer (score 1):

Where do obj1, obj2, obj3, etc come from? Are they props?

You can also spread an object as a component's props if that's easier

ie

```
const someObj = {
  duration: obj1,
  time: obj2,
  date: obj3,
  place: obj4
}

<SampleComponent {...someObj} />
```

This adds the props duration, time, date, place, etc to your component. Not sure if I have enough context, but maybe this can help

Comment: Updated the code. obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4 are from param itself.

Answer (score 1):

We can do something like this -:

Also added null fail safe check for the pops.

```
getPropsForSampleComponent = {
    duration: obj1 || null, 
    time: obj2 || null, 
    date: obj3 || null, 
    place: obj4 || null
}

render() {
    return (
        <SampleComponent
            {...this.getPropsForSampleComponent}
    )
}
```